# Get Active Directory Object Description Value

Tags: active-directory, ldap, jscript, wsh

I'm trying to get the "Description" attribute of a user object in our domain but it's resulting to a blank value even if it has a value in Active Directory Users and Computers.

I'm using the following code. I can't remember where I got it though. I modified it to quickly call it in other functions.

```js
function Getattrib(srchattrib, user, resattrib)
{
    var srchou = "OU=TheUsers,DC=MainDom,DC=net";
    var conn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
    conn.Open("Provider=ADsDSOObject");
    var rs = conn.Execute("<LDAP://"+srchou+">;("+srchattrib+"="+user+");"+resattrib+"");
    var i;
    if (!rs.EOF)
    {
        rs.MoveFirst();
        while(!rs.EOF)
        {
            return rs.Fields.Item(resattrib);
            rs.MoveNext();
        }
    }
}
```

It works perfectly when I do this:

```js
TexBox1.value = Getattrib('cn', 'James Sullivan', 'displayName');
```

But when I use:

```js
TexBox1.value = Getattrib('cn', 'James Sullivan', 'description');
```

Nothing comes up. I made sure that `James` has a `description` in the object properties in Active Directory between `Display Name` and `Office`.

Comment: Are you sure that 'description` is exist in current level of user? You need to loop through and display all the attributes on the screen or in the console and understand which nodes are available for access to get value.